# npm ERR! fatal: "Could not read from remote repository. " - "Please make sure you have the correct access rights"

Tags: npm

why I am getting this error when I run `npm install material-ui/core` -

npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/material-ui/core.git
npm ERR! ERROR: Repository not found.
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.

Please help me why I am getting this error and how can I solve this error?

Comment: In the [document](https://material-ui.com/), the command to install is `npm install @material-ui/core`. You're missing the '@' character